# Beginner: add simplify method to convert fraction class in simplest form and need a method to determine gcd

Tags: java

I am doing a school lab in which to add a public method to my fraction class. So the method will adds another fraction to the calling object and take the fraction class object as a parameter to return a fraction object as a result. Second is to add private simplify method to converts the fraction to simplest form and will need a method to determine the GCD.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab4Fraction {
    
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
        
    public void setNumerator(int num){
        numerator = num;    // to access data stored in numerator variable
    }
    
    public void inputValues(){  // refer to lab3 exercise 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter numerator : ");
        numerator = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter denominator : ");
        denominator = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if(denominator == 0)
            System.out.println("Invalid denominator!");
    }
    
    public void outputValues(){
        System.out.print(this);    // print as object to make use of toString() method
    }
    
    public int getNumerator(){
        return numerator;
    }
    
    public int getDenominator(){
        return denominator;
    }
    
    public void add(Fraction fracNum){
        numerator = numerator * fracNum.getDenominator() + fracNum.getNumerator() * denominator;
        denominator = denominator * fracNum.getDenominator();
    }
    
    public String toString() {  // to convert internal representation of fraction that stored 2 integers into a string
        String buffer = numerator + "/" + denominator;
        return buffer;
    }
    
    private void simplify(){   // this method is to reduce fraction 
        int GCD = GCD(numerator, denominator);
        numerator = numerator / GCD;
        denominator = denominator / GCD;
    }

    private int GCD(int numerator1, int numerator2) {  // to find greatest common denominator to reduce fractions
        int c;                                         // retrieve gcd code from  lab 4
        while (numerator1 != 0 && numerator2 != 0){
            c = numerator2;
            numerator2 = numerator1 % numerator2;      // modulo operator
            numerator1 = c;
        }
        return numerator1 + numerator2;
    }
    
}
```

for the test fraction

```
public class lab4TestFraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Fraction fracNumber = new Fraction();
        while(true){
            fracNumber.inputValues();
            if(fracNumber.getNumerator() < 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        fracNumber.outputValues();
    }

}
```

the output i got from this program is
[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdOw4.jpg)

which isn't the desired result i should get and am i able to do it without using constructor?

Comment: Look closely at what condition would cause control to come out of the while loop in your main method.

Comment: @k314159 erm but the while loop only break when user input any values for the numeration when is 0 or in negative. so how do i actually change the code for this loop?

Comment: You only print the output values when you're outside the while loop. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: @k314159 yes and i only stop the loop when negative value is entered for numerator

Comment: But don't you want to print the simplified fraction after every fraction is input? You're only printing the simplified fraction at the end when the program terminates.

Comment: @k314159 alright finally i get what you mean! thanks alot for the advice!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck